# uploading file via ftp using codeigniter but showing error message

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, ftp, filezilla

i am trying to upload file using ftp class of codeigniter, but it is showing me:

"Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path."

and in filezilla log i am getting: "550 Filename Invalid."

Please have a look on my code below and help me out to solve this issue.. i am usign xampp as my local server and filezilla as my ftp server on my local machine..

```
 $this->ftp->upload($_FILES['book_file']['tmp_name'], 
 'E:\\Software\\xampp-win32-1.8.2-2-VC9\\xampp\\htdocs\\international\\public\\books\\' . $_FILES['book_file']['name'],
 'ascii', 0775);
```

as suggested by **@KollleY** i have changed my code in this way:

```
 $this->ftp->upload($_FILES['book_file']['tmp_name'], 
 'ftp://localhost/' . $_FILES['book_file']['name'], 
 'ascii', 0775);
```

but again i am getting the same error:

"Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path."

while i can see all my files at `ftp://localhost/` using my web browser..

Comment: check the file extension

Comment: thanks @Sundar, the fileextension is not the issue..because i am getting "localhost/shointernational/public/books/simple_book.jpg" this log in my filezilla log

Answer (score 0):

you try to get file from your disc, but really, FTP should provide you with name, started with ftp://

Comment: thanks @KollleY sir, so according to the path i have given in my code what should i set it using ftp://

Comment: if you want to paste your file on your local disk, may be you can do it with "copy()" ?

Comment: i have tried this:
"f t p : / / localhost/shointernational/public/books/"
but again the same error..and i am only testing it in my local machine..i have a working code for the same for my online server..where i will host this website..but for testing purpose i am trying to set it on my local machine..

Comment: just look your FTP by web-browser and then copy path :D

Comment: can you suggest me.. what i should type in the web browser i have tried some url starting with ftp:// but it is saying not available

Comment: ftp://localhost/shointernational/public/books/

your link, of cource.

Comment: thank you so much @KollleY sir, because of you now i am getting all my files at ftp://   localhost/ on web browser..but again getting the same error "Unable to upload the specified file. Please check your path." can you suggest me any thing for this...

Comment: $this->ftp->upload($_FILES['book_file']['tmp_name'], 
 '//localhost/' . $_FILES['book_file']['name'],
 'ascii', 0775);

I think, it is.

Comment: again same error when using `//localhost/` or `/localhost/` and thank you very much..for your answer..but can you suggest any think else..

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['book_file']);die;

Comment: `array(5) { ["name"]=> string(13) "ftpupload.pdf" ["type"]=> string(15) "application/pdf" ["tmp_name"]=> string(57) "E:\Software\xampp-win32-1.8.2-2-VC9\xampp\tmp\php9E88.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(4304) }`

Comment: try to copy file to some directory from tmp first and then load it on FTP.

Comment: thank you very much, now i am skipping this..because i dont have that much time..and already it is working on my production server..so actually there is no need to test this on my local server..that is why i am skipping this..otherwise i had to solve this issue..but there is no need..and thank you very much sir...